# how to give a name to json object

Tags: java, json

how can i set a name to json object?

```
Map<String, ArrayList<String>> headerColumns = new LinkedHashMap<>();
headerColumns = gmailService.readMessgeAndProcess(session, MsgResponse, false, clientId);
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(headerColumns);
```

here jsonObject returns this output

```
[{"name":"aaaa","price":1133.43},
{"name":"bbbb","price":967.45}]
```

I tired to set the name to the jsonObject using **jsonObject.put("products", jsonObject);** but it doesn't work.

The expected output is

```
{"products": 
    [{"name":"aaaa","price":1133.43},
    {"name":"bbbb","price":967.45}]}
```

Comment: Which Json library are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just nested the data into another Map:

```
Map<String, ArrayList<String>> headerColumns = new LinkedHashMap<>();
Map<String, Object> products= new LinkedHashMap<>();
headerColumns = gmailService.readMessgeAndProcess(session, MsgResponse, false, clientId);
products.put("products", headerColumns)
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(products);
```